# Packaging multiple projects into one

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, module

I have multiple WAR projects which each contain a portion of a web apps logic, for example: one WAR would handle authentication while another would focus on messaging. I chose to do it this way to focus only on a single piece of the application at once ([Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

Some of these modules (WAR's) are dependent on others, though, I haven't coded the dependency parts yet (once they are "connected" I can allow them to communicate appropriately). So, I need to package these different WAR's together. What I believe my options are:

- **EAR file.** The problem with this approach is that WAR's within an EAR file do not maintain a single session between them.
- **Maven.** Unfortunately, I have little experience with Maven.
- **Manually add each package to new WAR.** How would I define the folder structure? Multiple source folders or multiples packages within single source folder?

So, my question: **How would I package multiple projects into one?**

Answer (score 0):

Maven is kind of orthogonal to your problem.

If I were you I would just build a single web application (WAR) with all of the source in a single source folder. Use the java `package` structure to separate your concerns. This will also simplify your development process.

If the number of java source files becomes large you might consider splitting them out into jar projects and adding the subsequent jar files to your WAR file's WEB-INF/lib directory. Maven would then be useful to build your dependent jar files and assemble the WAR.

And please don't build your own authentication subsystem. You could use [Container Managed Authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) or if more sophistication is needed [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) or [Key Cloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org), any of which may solve your problem with zero lines of code.